# Get first N chars and sort them

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, cut

I have a requirement where i need to fetch  first four characters from each line of file and sort them.

I tried below way. but its not sorting each line

```
cut -c1-4 simple_file.txt | sort -n
```

**O/p using above:**

```
appl
bana
uoia
```

**Expected output:**

```
alpp
aabn
aiou
```

Comment: What's in simple_file.txt?

Answer (score 3):

`sort` isn't the right tool for the job in this case, as it used to sort lines of input, not the characters within each line.

I know you didn't tag the question with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) but here's one way you could do it:

```
perl -F'' -lane 'print(join "", sort @F[0..3])' file
```

This uses the `-a` switch to auto-split each line of input on the delimiter specified by `-F` (in this case, an empty string, so each character is its own element in the array `@F`). It then sorts the first 4 characters of the array using the standard string comparison order. The result is joined together on an empty string.

Comment: Another perl way but similar `perl -lpe '$_=join"",sort split//,substr($_,0,4)'`

Answer (score 2):

Try defining two helper functions:

```
explodeword () {
        test -z "$1" && return
        echo ${1:0:1}
        explodeword ${1:1}
}

sortword () {
        echo $(explodeword $1 | sort) | tr -d ' '
}
```

Then

```
cut -c1-4 simple_file.txt | while read -r word; do sortword $word; done
```

will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` command is used to sort files line by line, it's not designed to sort the contents of a line. It's not impossible to make sort do what you want, but it would be a bit messy and probably inefficient.

I'd probably do this in Python, but since you *might* not have Python, here's a short awk command that does what you want.

```awk
awk '{split(substr($0,1,4),a,"");n=asort(a);s="";for(i=1;i<=n;i++)s=s a[i];print s}'
```

Just put the name of the file (or files) that you want to process at the end of the command line.

Here's some data I used to test the command:

**data**

```
this
is a
simple
test file

a
of
apple
banana
cat
uoiea
bye
```

And here's the output

```
hist
 ais
imps
estt

a
fo
alpp
aabn
act
eiou
bey
```

---

Here's an ugly Python one-liner; it would look a bit nicer as a proper script rather than as a Bash command line:

```python
python -c "import sys;print('\n'.join([''.join(sorted(s[:4])) for s in open(sys.argv[1]).read().splitlines()]))"
```

In contrast to the awk version, this command can only process a single file, and it reads the whole file into RAM to process it, rather than processing it line by line.

Comment: I was considering going down this route - one thing worth mentioning is that `asort` is a GNU awk feature.

Comment: @TomFenech: Oh well, so it is. Hopefully, Bubbles is on a GNU system. :) FWIW, `perl` looks like it's the winner for this task, in terms of conciseness & elegance. Your code is certainly smaller than anything I can come up with in Python.